# Test POST method in web.py

Tags: python, webserver, http-post

I would like to post/upload a file to a web server written using some simple web.py code.

On the web server code I have some simple url mapping:

```
urls = (
'/results', 'results',
'/results/(.*)', 'get_result'
)
```

With class results:

```
class results:
def GET(self):
    output = 'objects:[Non-real-example,50%]'
    return output

def POST(self):
    #data = web.input()
    #data = web.data()
    return 'received data'
```

I also have a client testing app:

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/results/post'
payload = {'image': open('../../data/seth.jpg', 'rb')}

def testpostmethod():
    r = requests.post(url,data=payload)
    return r.text
```

However, I keep getting the error '127.0.0.1:55126 - - [16/Feb/2016 07:43:30] "HTTP/1.1 POST /results/post" - 405 Method Not Allowed'

How do I make the POST method accessible to the client test code so that I can upload my image file?

Comment: I don't know anything about web.py, but from this code it seems clear that the get and post methods you have defined are associated with /results, not /results/post - that would be matched against get_results, surely?

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman. The second part of the URL tuple, as I understand it, redirects to the 'results' class. So a post on the results should be handled by the results class which is the second snippet of code.

Comment: oh you're right! The 'post' is not part of the URL.